# Sibling Selectors not working correctly with Emotion

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, emotion, css-in-js

I have the following code:

```
const CardContainer = styled(Flex)`
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(218, 228, 242);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 12px 2px rgba(black, 0.6);
  transition: 0.2s;

  &:not(:first-child) {
    background: red;
    margin-left: -50px;
  }

  &:hover,
  &:focus-within {
    transform: translatey(-1rem);
  }

  &:hover ~ &,
  &:focus-within ~ & {
    transform: translatex(50px);
  } 
`;
```

But the last statement is not working. The CSS code that I'm trying to copy is:

```
.card:hover ~ .card,
.card:focus-within ~ .card {
  transform: translatex(50px);
}
```

And here is the original codepen:

> https://codepen.io/toddwebdev/pen/yWMgQX?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this instead:

```
& + ${() => CardContainer} {
  transform: translateX(var(--distance));
}
```

Also your `import styled from "@emotion/styled` has to be `import styled from "@emotion/styled/macro` in order to support the above.

**Note:** changed the `styled(Flex)` to `styled("section")` to prevent errors in sandbox

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

---

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled/macro";
import "./styles.css";

const CardContainer = styled("section")`
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(218, 228, 242);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 12px 2px rgba(black, 0.6);
  transition: 0.2s;

  &:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-left: -50px;
  }

  &:hover,
  &:focus-within {
    transform: translateY(-1rem);

    & + ${() => CardContainer} {
      transform: translateX(var(--distance));
    }
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="cards">
      <CardContainer>
        <div className="card">
          <h1>
            <a href="#0">Title</a>
          </h1>
          <p>This is an article and this has some content.</p>
        </div>
      </CardContainer>
      <CardContainer>
        <div className="card">
          <h1>
            <a href="#0">Title</a>
          </h1>
          <p>This is an article and this has some content.</p>
        </div>
      </CardContainer>
      <CardContainer>
        <div className="card">
          <h1>
            <a href="#0">Title</a>
          </h1>
          <p>This is an article and this has some content.</p>
        </div>
      </CardContainer>
      <CardContainer>
        <div className="card">
          <h1>
            <a href="#0">Title</a>
          </h1>
          <p>This is an article and this has some content.</p>
        </div>
      </CardContainer>
      <CardContainer>
        <div className="card">
          <h1>
            <a href="#0">Title</a>
          </h1>
          <p>This is an article and this has some content.</p>
        </div>
      </CardContainer>
    </div>
 );
}
```